# require other library (jquery or etc.) in vue.js

Tags: javascript, webpack, vue.js

I can not connect a third-party js library to vue.js component

main.js

```
...
require('jquery')
import Vue from 'vue'
import VueMdl from 'vue-mdl'
import App from './App'
import Auth from './views/user/Auth'
import Index from './views/Index'
import VueRouter from 'vue-router'
import VueResource from 'vue-resource'

Vue.use(VueRouter)
Vue.use(VueMdl)
Vue.use(VueResource)

const AppComponent = Vue.extend(App)
new AppComponent({
  router,
  el: '#app',
  template: '<App/>',
  components: { App }
})
```

RegisterModal.vue

```
<template>
  ...
</template>

    <script>
      export default {
        name: 'register',
        data () {
          return {
            msg: 'Register'
          }
        },
        methods: {
          open () {
            this.$refs.register.open()
          },
          close () {
            this.$refs.register.close()
          },
          submit () {
            var data = $('form').serialize() //  '$' is not defined
            console.log(jQuery) // 'jQuery' is not defined
            console.log(data);
          }
        }
      }
    </script>
```

require with webpack

```
plugins: [
new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
$ : "jquery",
jQuery : "jquery",
})
],
```

not working too

How to solve my problem and to make available any library within the component?

Answer (score 1):

I think might need to declare `jQuery` globally as well, like so:

```
new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
    $: "jquery",
    jQuery: "jquery",
    "window.jQuery": "jquery"
});
```

or:

```
window.$ = window.jQuery = require('jquery');
```

Answer (score 0):

1.import `$` in RegisterModal.vue

```
<script>
  import $ from 'jQuery';
</script>
```

2. add `externals` configuration to webpack.config.js

```
externals: {
      jQuery: 'window.jQuery'
 }
```

Answer (score -1):

Whilst facing the same issue I came across [this useful article](https://vuejsdevelopers.com/2017/04/22/vue-js-libraries-plugins/) which suggests that

> The cleanest and most robust way to use a Javascript library in a Vue
>   project is to proxy it to a property of the Vue prototype object.
>   Let's do that to add the Moment date and time library to our project:
>   (entry.js)

```
import moment from 'moment';
Object.defineProperty(Vue.prototype, '$moment', { value: moment });
```

He explains that

> Since all components inherit their methods from the Vue prototype
>   object this will make Moment automatically available across any and
>   all components with no global variables or anything to manually
>   import. It can simply be accessed in any instance/component from
>   this.$moment

After some fiddling I got it working nicely for me, e.g. using `props` in a child `component`

```
<p v-if="enrolment.eventBookings.length > 0">{{$moment(enrolment.eventBookings[0].bookable.startTime).format("HH:mm")}}</p>
```

So kudos to the author!